# Why are three rows from a MySQL query not in the correct order?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I don't know if this is a bug with MySQL or my fault, but it is really starting to get on my nerves.

To get the answers of a user, I use this query (which also makes sure the question is not deleted or hidden):

```
  SELECT *
    FROM answers a
    JOIN questions q
      ON a.questionid = q.qid
   WHERE a.userid = <uid> -- query parameter
     AND a.deleted = 0
     AND q.hidden = 0
     AND q.deleted = 0
ORDER BY a.created DESC
```

The problem is that all of the answers are in order by the timestamp of the time that they were created, *except* for three of them. In this screenshot of the answers on my profile, take a look at the dates of answers on the questions that say "This question has an issue with the ordering...":

[image]

I really do not know what is happening. As you can see the MySQL query has `ORDER BY a.created DESC`.

---

**What have I tried?**

Well, I have tried many things, like echoing out the Unix Timestamp stored in the DB and they're all correct.

Another thing I tried is calling `strtotime()` on the timestamps, but that only gave me more issues: the first one was oddly turned into a huge negative number and displayed *Aug 3, 1717* but the others were made blank and therefore said *Dec 31, 1969*.

---

#### Edit

It looks like a couple of other of rows are mixed up as well.

---

#### Solution

I discovered that both the `questions` table and the `answers` table have a `created` column. I fixed this by doing `SELECT *, a.created as ans_created, q.created as q_created` and it now works. Thank you to everyone that helped.

Comment: Does this query return the same result set if run direct in MySQL?

Comment: Can you reduce the problem set to a few rows for example by using `question.id IN ( 3,4,5)` which still reproduces the error? And maybe you could try to create an http://sqlfiddle.com/ example with those rows.

Comment: What date are you displaying? Are you ordering by answer date. Maybe you want to order by question date?

Comment: @liaant Haven't tried that yet - will try it soon.

Comment: @arnep Yeah, I am ordering by answer date (and also displaying it) because it has to be ordered by the answer date. It is showing the answers of the user and the question title is there just to show what question it is on.

Comment: @liaant Yes, when the query is run directly in the MySQL client and in phpMyAdmin, it returns the same result set.

Comment: what is data type of column `a.created`?

Comment: What is your exact MySQL version? It might be simply buggy.

Comment: @Omesh It is an `int`. Whenever I insert something (an answer, a question, etc.) I put the current unix time in it using php's `time()` function.

Comment: @biziclop My MySQL version is `5.5.9`.

Comment: try changing it to int unsigned as unix time returns unsigned int.

Comment: `strtotime` expects a date-formatted string as input (not a timestamp) - use `date` instead. I'd display the raw `int`s from the database to see if there is a problem with that. This is likely to be where the problem is, especially if you use InnoDB. If not, the DB / index could be corrupted - try to regenerate the index.

Comment: I already use `date`. However, I was just trying it out (obviously it didn't work). I did display the raw `int`s from the DB and they are normal tiemstamps (I even tried putting the ones that are in the wrong order in the "Convert Unix timestamp or date" Chrome extension and it outputs the correct date.

Comment: Well it looks like I just found the problem, and it is my fault. The `question` table has a `created` column as well as the `answers` table. It must be ordering by the answer creation date, but displaying the question creation date. I can't believe I didn't see that earlier. :/

Comment: " *It must be ordering by the answer creation date, but displaying the question creation date* " Would you mind to elaborate? How is that possible...

Comment: @ring0 Because in the query I ordered by `a.created` but in my PHP I echoed the date like this: `date('M j, Y g:i A', $row['created'])`. What I had to do is select `a.created as a_created` and `q.created as q_created`. Then, in the PHP I did: `date('M j, Y g:i A', $row['a_created'])`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am just going to answer my own question since I figured out what the problem is.

I discovered that both the questions table and the answers table have a `created` column.

**The problem was that I was ordering by `a.created` in the query but since in the PHP I displayed the date with `$row['created']` it was ordering correctly but displaying an incorrect date/time.**

I fixed this by doing...

```
SELECT *, a.created as ans_created, q.created as q_created
```

And then in my PHP I just do `$row['ans_created']`.

Thank you to everyone that helped in the comments and the other answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

try `CAST` on column `a.created` as:

```
ORDER BY CAST(a.created AS DATETIME) DESC;
```

IF you are using INT field then try:

```
ORDER BY CAST(a.created AS UNSIGNED INTEGER) DESC;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that just made it seem like it is ascending `ASC` now and I even tried putting `ASC` but it has the oldest answer at the top now and the newest at the bottom. It didn't fix the problem with those three answers not of order either.

Comment: Thanks, but it looks like I just found the problem, and it was my fault. The `question` table has a `created` column as well as the `answers` table. It must be ordering by the answer creation date, but displaying the question creation date. I can't believe I didn't see that earlier. :/

Comment: Okay. Hope you got your answer. :)